# Editor similar to Compare Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there an example showing editor similar to Eclipse Compare Editor (simplified)? I am looking for a way to create an editor which is split in two parts where top part is DSL and bottom is AST of DSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like direction I should go is to use a Composite like SashForm when creating control in the editor during createPartControl(Composite parent) call.

After playing around with editor, which extends TextEditor, but any editor will do, I came up with this:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(parent, SWT.VERTICAL);
    sashForm.setLayout(new RowLayout());

    super.createPartControl(sashForm);

    Button label2 = new Button(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    label2.setText("TEST2");
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is the org.eclipse.compare.CompareConfiguration class. After that, you can review usage in org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.TextEditChangePreviewViewer.ComparePreviewer, org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareEditor/org.eclipse.compare.CompareEditorInput ... There are a lot editors/views in Eclipse which use this stuff.

Comment: I looked at Compare editor, but all implementations are tied to org.eclipse.compare, which is fine. But I wanted to see if there is something simpler that creates similar split editor.